# Does the Function Between Some Set and N Has Any Properties? (Question about Countable Set)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

(Note that when I say countable, it means countable infinite)

My question is that, the definition of a countable set is

> $S$ is said to be a countable set if there is a bijective function $f:\mathbb N\mapsto S$

But isn't countable a topological property ? Does the function f have more properties like continuous or $f^{-1}$ continuous ?

More precisely, if $S$ is a countable set, does the function $f:\mathbb N\mapsto S$ need to be

1. $f$ continuous
2. $f^{-1}$ continuous

Seems that I can show the first one because every subset of $\mathbb N$ is open (and closed) on $\mathbb N$, then for every subset of $S$, $f^{-1}(S)$ must be an open subset of $\mathbb N$, so f is continuous.

Is the second one right? I think not, but I can't give a counterexample. (I think it's wrong because if it's true, the f is a homeomorphism but the text book doesn't tell that)

Comment: Countability has nothing to do with topology. You may be confusing countability (a set theoretic notion) with first and second coubtability (topological notions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, being countable is not a topological property.  Any bijection $f$ is fine to establish the countability of $S$.  You don't even have to define the bijection, you just have to show one exists.

Comment: so you mean that countability isn't that important in topology?
because I've been confused for a long time, about countable. It's so hard to prove.

Comment: Most topological spaces I have seen have an uncountable number of points (though there are spaces that have a countable or finite number  of points)  First and second countable in topology depends on having a countable basis, not a countable number of points.